# How Can I Get my (Linux) Computer to Use Nvidia Drivers?

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card, linux-mint, nvidia-graphics-card

I'm on Linux Mint 18 (MATE).

A week or so ago I made the terrible, terrible mistake of allowing the update manager to update my packages for me, and since then I haven't been able to get my graphics to work.

After much struggling and reading of other Super User questions I've:

- Purged all Nvidia packages
- Reinstalled the nvidia-384 package

  - plus some related packages like `nvidia-settings` and `nvidia-prime`
  - (Prime is a feature for computers like mine that have both a built-in Intel graphics card and a separate NVidia one; it's *supposed* to let me use both in an intelligent way, but at this point I'd settle for just using the Nvidia card 100% of the time)
- Ran `sudo update-alternatives --config x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf` and picked Nvidia (this doesn't seem to matter; whatever I pick it gets reset after I reboot)
- Ran `nvidia-xconfig` to generate a fresh xorg.conf
- I even edited my GRUB config so that it wouldn't choose the Noveau driver:

  - `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash noveau.modset=0"`

But my computer still refuses to use the Nvidia drivers, or at least fully.  They're sort of working ... if I run:

```
 lspci | grep -i nvidia
```

I get:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104M [GeForce GTX 870M] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

(before it wasn't listing anything).  Also if I run:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf
```

it *sees* the Nvidia option, but no matter how many times I select it it reverts back to the Mesa option after I reboot:

```
There are 3 choices for the alternative x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf (providing /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf).

  Selection    Path                                       Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/nvidia-384/ld.so.conf              8604      auto     mode
  1            /usr/lib/nvidia-384-prime/ld.so.conf        8603      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/nvidia-384/ld.so.conf              8604      manual mode
* 3            /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf   500       manual mode
```

But when I run `nvidia-settings` it just tells me `ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system`, and if I run `sudo prime-select query` after a reboot it just says "Unknown".  I can then run `sudo prime-select nvidia` and it will pick Nvidia ... but then (like the alternatives file) it will go back to unknown after the next reboot.

So, I feel like I'm really close, and I just need to do *something* to get my computer to both use the Nvidia driver and, more importantly, keep using it after I reboot.  Can anyone help?

P.S. One other way I can tell the NVidia driver isn't being used is that I can't see my second monitor (well third if you count the laptop display monitor), which is plugged into the Nvidia card; I can only see the laptop and monitor #1.  When the Nvidia card is working I can see both monitors.

P.P.S.  I also tried removing the MESA driver from the alternatives list with `sudo update-alternatives --remove x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf`, but it didn't help.  Now when I run `sudo update-alternatives --config x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf` it claims that `/usr/lib/nvidia-390/ld.so.conf` is being used, but when I try to run `nvidia-settings` it claims otherwise:

```
ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded


ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system
```

Comment: Why are you not just using Driver Manager?

Comment: I have used it, but it hasn't helped.  I currently have it set on nvidia-384.  What's odd is that it has options for 390 and 396, which I don't even have installed anymore, but back when I had them installed I tried switching to them with the driver manager, and it did no good.

Comment: I would also recommend Driver Manager but what you described seems correct, IMO. Maybe I'm missing something important or maybe you didn't clean it properly before reinstalling the drivers. Are you sure you used `sudo apt purge nvidia*`? The asterisk matters.

Comment: I'm using 396 at the moment, not issues. Could it be the problem started because of the downgrade? Anyway, it shouldn't matter if all nvidia stuff have been purged (command in the previous comment).

Comment: Yes, I definitely ran `sudo apt purge nvidia*` :(  Then I re-installed 384.  As for the problem starting, it started when I **up**graded.  I'm not sure which exact package caused it because I blindly used the update manager, foolishly thinking it would be safe.

Comment: Just ran everything again to double-check, and tried 396 this time: `sudo  apt-get purge nvidia*` `sudo apt install nvidia-396 nvidia-settings`, check driver manager (it has already switched to 396), reboot, and ... `nvidia-settings` `ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system`.  But `lspci | grep -i nvidia` shows `01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104M [GeForce GTX 870M] (rev a1)`, and the Driver Manager still thinks I'm on 396.

Comment: Oh and `sudo update-alternatives --config x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf` is back on  `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

It wound up being the strangest thing.  In some random forum post someone suggested that the Secure Boot setting in the BIOS could cause the problem, so I rebooted, went into the BIOS settings, and sure enough it was on.  I turned it off, continued booting, and suddenly everything worked normally afterwards.